# External Functions "not defined" warning JSHINT

Tags: angularjs, controller, undefined, jshint

I'm using AngularJS to create an app and i'm using an external library to hash strings.

```
<script src="bower_components/blueimp-md5/js/md5.js"></script>
```

In a controller i call md5() function that hash a string.

```
md5(myKey);
```

This works but Jshint gives me a warning : md5 is not defined

How to avoid that and what's the best way to call external libraries ?

Thks in advance.

**Edit : I set "md5": true in my .jshintrc, I don't have the warning anymore but is that the best practice ?**

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add definition in .jshintrc file in section "globals" to avoid warnings  like this:

```
{
  "blabla": true,
  "globals": {
    "md5": true
  }
}
```